# SQL Server Group rows with multiple occurences of Group BY columns

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to summarize a dataset and get the minimum and maximum date for each group.  However, a group can exist multiple times if there is a gap.  Here is sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE temp (
id int,
FIRSTNAME nvarchar(50),
LASTNAME  nvarchar(50),
STARTDATE datetime2(7),
ENDDATE   datetime2(7)
)

INSERT into temp values(1,'JOHN','SMITH','2013-04-02','2013-05-31')
INSERT into temp values(2,'JOHN','SMITH','2013-05-31','2013-10-31')
INSERT into temp values(3,'JANE','DOE','2013-10-31','2016-07-19')
INSERT into temp values(4,'JANE','DOE','2016-07-19','2016-08-11')
INSERT into temp values(5,'JOHN','SMITH','2016-08-11','2017-02-01')
INSERT into temp values(6,'JOHN','SMITH','2017-02-01','9999-12-31')
```

I am looking to summarize the data as follows:

```
JOHN    SMITH   2013-04-02  2013-10-31
JANE    DOE     2013-10-31  2016-08-11
JOHN    SMITH   2016-08-11  9999-12-31
```

A "group by" will combine the two John Smith records together with the incorrect min and max dates.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a [gaps and islands](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/) problem. They are not super easy to solve, but it's totally doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JNevill pointed out, this is a classic Gaps and Islands problem.  Below is one solution using **Row_Number()**.

```
Select FirstName
      ,LastName
      ,StartDate=min(StartDate)
      ,EndDate  =max(EndDate)
 From (
        Select *
              ,Grp = Row_Number() over (Order by ID) - Row_Number() over (Partition By FirstName,LastName Order by EndDate)
         From  Temp
      ) A
 Group By FirstName,LastName,Grp
 Order By min(StartDate)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I didn't even know how to classify it when searching.  Now I know, gaps and islands.

Comment: @user4956435 Happy it helped

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT firstName,
       lastName,
       MIN( startDate ) AS earliestStartDate,
       MAX( endDate ) AS latestEndDate
FROM temp
GROUP BY firstName,
         lastName;
```

This statement will use the `GROUP BY` statement to group together the records based on `firstName` and `lastName` combinations.  It will then return the `firstName` and `lastName` for each group as well as the earliest `startDate` for that group courtesy of the `MIN()` function and the latest `endDate` for that group courtesy of the `MAX()` function.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.